# Ubuntu 14.04 On Acer Aspire TImelinex 3830T Microphone

Tags: acer, microphone, 14.04

Okay so the microphone has been staticy ever since installing ubuntu starting with 12.10 does anyone have a fix for the microphone?

Answer (score 0):

Install pavucontrol, go to the recording options, disable "Lock channels together" or something like that. Put one channel (left or right) in half the other channel.

If I understand correctly your problem, it can be because when the 2 channels of the mic are in the same level, they cancel each other. I have a  5830TG and had the same problem, and fixed that way, no need to disable the PulseAudio